# Proper way to say, thanks for your "careness"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

What is the proper way to say, if I want to express, thanks for your "careness"?

I mean, I want to express, thanks for *being care* about me, i.e., thanking them for always having me on their mind, (or my illness, my pursuit etc), and kind enough to care & ask.

I know that "*thanks for being care about me*" is the about right what I want to express, however, I'm feeling that it has the underline meaning that I'm being weak, which is not the case. It's more about "*thanks for your concern*", but "*concern*" is too strong, and too serious to me.

This is not for a close friend, but someone I know from the Internet. I once told him, long time ago, that I'm determined to learn so and so, and 8+ months later, he still remember, and care enough to ask "*how is it going*", and I want to thank him for that, in a sentence as vague and as short possible, but still to the point.

thx

Comment: The word is caring, not careness.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to say this.  The two simplest expressions are:

> Thanks for **caring about** me.
>
> Thanks for **thinking about** me.

Depending on the context, "care" might sound too familiar.  Instead you could say:

> Thanks for **following up with** me.  Yes, after you helped me out, I understand the material much better.

Other expressions of gratitude for those closer to you, especially those who regularly help you:

> Thanks for **taking (good) care of me**.
>
> Thanks for **looking after** me.
>
> Thanks for **always thinking about** me.
>
> Thanks for **keeping me in your thoughts**.